# Spawn distance algorithm in 2D array

Tags: algorithm, distance

for a school project I am developing a Bomberman-like, I need to be able to handle an infinite number of players.

The problem is that I am supposed to initialize them each in their own spawn (because we don't want them to be too close to each others).

```
Keep a list of all possible [x;y]
Randomly pick a [x;y] value
Remove all the [x;y] from the list around the player with a range of 3
```

Something like this would create a "zone" spawn and would work but I am pretty curious and would be willing to discuss algorithm approach to find the greatest distance possible so that for n players we have the best optimal solution in term of distance from each other.

Any idea ?

Comment: What about placing the first player in the middle, and then let a list of "next spawn location"s spiral out from this one? With some min/max distance from earlier positions.

Comment: try Lloyd's algorithm  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm

Comment: You will need to define the optimal distance more specifically. For example, increasing the distance of the spawn from a player from 13 squares to 14 squares is less important than increasing the distance from 3 squares to 4 squares. So there needs to be some kind function to define this.